# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in on line 28

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my first project on PHP and first time encounter this bug which really can't solve after struggle one day.
Can any expert and kind soul here advise how to resolve this error please? My PHP version is 5.6.

Thank you so much,

After I submit my form, it shows below error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in on line 28

My DB connection coding is

```
<?php 
 $DSN= 'mysql:host = localhost; dbname=cms4.2.1';
 $ConnectingDB = new PDO($DSN, 'root', '');

 ?>

Category page that shows line 28 got error on the POD function "prepare"
 if(empty($Category))
{
 $SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "All fields must be filled out";
 Redirect_to("Categories.php");
 } elseif (strlen($Category)<3) {
 $SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Category Title should be greater than 3      
 characters";
 Redirect_to("Categories.php");
 } elseif (strlen($Category)>49) {
 $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Category Title should be less than 50  
 characters";
 Redirect_to("Categories.php");
  } else {
 global $ConnectingDB;
 $sql = "INSERT INTO category(title,author,datetime)";
 $sql .="VALUES(:categoryName,:adminName,:dateTime)";
 $stmt = $ConnectingDB->prepare($sql); // - > means PDO object rotation -   
 Line 28
 $stmt->bindValue(':categoryName',$Category);
 $stmt->bindValue(':adminName',$Admin);
 $stmt->bindValue(':dateTime',$DateTime);
 $Execute=$stmt->execute();
```

Please assist. Thank you so much.

Comment: please use var_dump to check the $ConnectingDB variable after this line:
" global $ConnectingDB;"
it seams is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to remove spaces here: `mysql:host = localhost; dbname=cms4.2.1` would be `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms4.2.1`

Also, wrap the connecting statement in a try-catch block to see if you connect correctly.

```
try {
    $DSN = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms4.2.1';
    $ConnectingDB = new PDO($DSN, 'root', '');
    $ConnectingDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Hi Anurag

Thank you sooo much. Is due to the spacing that made the things not work...

Thank you for your help. I am really a new user to PHP.

Comment: I wish to accept the answer too but can't find where to click? :-( Any advise? Thank you.

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle.